# How to get values for a queryset for an model when the foreign key is not in the current model?

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I have the following models:

```
class Work_Music(models.Model):
    key = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True, blank=True)
    tonality = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)

class Catalogue(models.Model):
    work_music = models.ForeignKey(Work_Music, verbose_name=_('work_music'), on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    name_short = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    no = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
```

related_field() only works with the Foreign key is in Work_Music. Many catalogue/catalogue numbers can map to a piece of music (Work_Music). How can I construct a query set on Work_Music to pull all of the catalogues related to the piece of work?

Answer (score 0):

Use catalogue_set.

Django's ORM automatically creates the field for you on the navigation model of the foreign key (Work_Music in this case). For "one-to-many" relationships, this is a queryset with the name of the model on which the foreign key exists appended with `_set`. For "one-to-one" relationships, this is just the name of the model on which the foreign key exists.

assuming a Work_Music instance called `work_music_instance`:

```
catalogues = work_music_instance.catalogue_set.all()
```

or

```
catalogues = work_music_instance.catalogue_set.filter(...) # any query set operation
```

Comment: Thanks this is helpful. What if I want to join both Work_Music and Catalogue model so that I have the work and the catalogue together to send as context for a template?

Comment: Context is a dictionary. So you can store whatever you want in any key in the context to access it in the template. You can also call parameterless methods in the context, so you can call something like `{% for catalogue in work_music_instance.catalogue_set.all %}` assuming you set work_music_instance in the context to a Work_Music model instance

Answer (score -1):

First get an object whose catalogue you want.

```
   workmusic = Work_Music.objects.all()[0]
```

then

```
   workmusic.catalogue_set.all()
```

this will return all catalogue related to workmusic object.

Comment: so you can't grab the catalogue for the whole set?

Comment: No we can't grab the catalogue for the whole set of WorkMusic.

Comment: we can grab the catalogue for a instance of WorkMusic